# Will changing http to https affect my android app which had hardcoded http urls

Tags: android, http, https

I have a live android app which uses http version of the server. I am changing http to https in the server keeping the hardcoded http urls in the app same. Will my app still work? Or I have to update my app?

Comment: If you have only GET requests and if you haven't turned followRedirects off, it should work, if your server just redirects from http to https. If you have POST requests, you might run into troubles, as POST data is not redirected automatically as a security precaution. It would help if you tell us more of your networking architecture. Do you use specific libraries? What kind of calls do you make, is there anything out of the ordinary

Comment: you can also create a test instance of your server that already has https and you can build your client with http urls that point to the new instance and check if everything works as expected.

Comment: @ peshkira, I make post request to get json response from the server.